# Street view app and Gmap API loading time

Tags: api, maps, google-street-view

I'm create an app based on Street View API, I have to wait for the panorama to load to proceed for further function and stuff.

But, the loading time of the Gmap API is incredibly slow (somewhere between 5 to 20 seconds...).

When I'm take a look at the inspector, the code wait for the common.js file of gmaps api this long.

Here is a printscreen of the inspector :
http://imageshack.com/a/img540/687/3BBxe4.jpg

any thought ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out.

Find somewhere I should use the async method for loading GMAP, my app is loading immediatly even if there is a lot of gmap stuff remain to load.

Work like a charm !